# Does iOS programming in Xcode allow execution of a binary file?

Tags: ios, process

Does iOS using Xcode allow execution of a binary file?
(Creating a process using an external binary file)

Comment: Xcode is an IDE. It has nothing to do with your question which I assume is really asking if an App Store approved iOS app, running on a non-jailbroken device, can launch (exec) another binary. Is that actually your question?

Comment: Yes that's the question, sorry for the confusion. The binary is included in the package.

Comment: An IDE is a fancy editor/compiler, nothing more. Xcode has nothing to do with an app executing a file. It is the app that executes a file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about App Store policies and not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is really asking if an App Store approved iOS app, running on a non-jailbroken device, can launch (exec) another binary, then the answer is no.

From the App Review Guidelines:

> Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

Non-Apple approved apps can do so but not apps meant for the App Store.